# Inheritance method overwrite in some conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, overriding

I need to overwrite a method in a Python class, however this method needs to keep his behaviour in certain condition. An example of what I need:

```
class DefaultClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 5

    def do_something(self, x):
        self.number = self.number * x 
        return self.number

class ChildClass(DefaultClass):
     def __init__(self):
         self.flag = False

     def do_something(self, x):
         if self.flag is False:
             # do_something method should works as defined in DefaultClass
         else:
             self.number = self.number + x
             return self.number
```

An important point here, I dont have access to the implementation of the method that I want to overwrite (life is not so simple).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use super() 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: @Howaboutnope you can post this as an answer :)

Comment: So call the original method with `super()`: `return super().do_something(x)`.

Comment: @DeepSpace: no, we are looking for the best canonical to close this to as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes.. I forgot the super()